# Reloading UITabBar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

our iOS8+ application can have the color theme changed remotely. We use the following code to change the tab bar

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor brandColor]];
```

However this only seems to work in the appdelegate  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. If we use it anywhere else the new color only affects the tab bar if a view is pushed which hides the tabbar so that when it reappears the new color applies. Is there some way of reloading the `UITabBar` view so the color is applied as soon as the `setTintColor` method is called.

Thanks

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23414500/655548

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652957/uinavigationbar-appearance-refresh) answer

> The appearance proxy only affects the look of newly initialized views. Setting colors on the appearance proxy will have no effect on tab bar that is already visible.